# How to import and update subpackages using VGO

Tags: go, dependencies, package

I'm just learning how to use VGO and it seems like a very simple problem but I could not find any good example explaining how to solve it.

I have project hosted in a private bitbucket repository. Let's assume the project URL is `bitbucket.org/mycompany/myapp`

At the root level I have the `main.go`, which imports from a subpackage. The import looks like this:

```
import "bitbucket.org/mycompany/myapp/subpackage"
```

Question 1. After I just added that subpackage I do "`vgo get .`" because I want to fetch some other libraries, but that fails because it tries also to fetch my subpackage from bitbucket rather than using my local version. Obviously, I have not committed my changes so that fetch fails with "remote: Not Found" error. Do I have to push my changes before I do "`vgo get .`" ?

Question 2. Assuming I have my subpackage in the repository, but I made a small change something in it. Now I want to verify it it works, do I have always push every single change every time before I do `vgo build`?

In general, is there a way to tell vgo that if an absolute import path refers to my local repository it should take the files from the filesystem, rather than pulling from the bitbucket.org?

Comment: try replacing, see https://research.swtch.com/vgo-tour; e.g. `replace rsc.io/quote v1.5.2 => ../quote`